Vertex ai takes 19s when executed from nodejs
I'm experimenting with Vertex AI, and while it works perfectly (responding in under 3 seconds) when I run it from Vertex AI Studio, the same code takes 19 seconds or more when executed with Node.js. Here’s the code I’m using—any ideas on what I might be missing?
// Initialize Vertex with your Cloud project and location
const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({project: 'test-project', location: 'us-central1'});
const model = 'gemini-1.5-flash-002';

// Instantiate the models
const generativeModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
  model: model,
  generationConfig: {
    'maxOutputTokens': 8192,
    'temperature': 1,
    'topP': 0.95,
  },
  safetySettings: [
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    }
  ],
  tools: [
    {
      googleSearchRetrieval: {},
    },
  ],
});


async function generateContent() {
  const req = {
    contents: [
      {role: 'user', parts: [{text: `what\'s a good name for a flower shop that specializes in selling bouquets of dried flowers?\"`}]}
    ],
  };
  console.time("Generate Content Response Time");

  const response = await generativeModel.generateContent(req);
  console.timeEnd("Generate Content Response Time");
 console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

  //process.stdout.write('aggregated response: ' + JSON.stringify(await streamingResp.response));
}

generateContent();

i thought to get response in 3 seconds as i saw in vertex ai studio

One of the main reasons I see why it took 19 seconds to run in Node.js is because the Vertex AI SDK for Node.js lets you use the Vertex AI Gemini API to build AI-powered features and applications. Both TypeScript and JavaScript are supported. The sample code in this document is written in JavaScript. There are additional installations that might take some time before it fully executes the code.
Key Factors Contributing to Latency Differences:

Network Latency: Direct communication within the Vertex AI platform in Studio often results in lower latency compared to network requests in Node.js applications.

Model Loading Time: Models might be pre-loaded or cached in Studio, reducing initial load times. In Node.js, models need to be loaded for each request.

Prediction Request Processing: Studio might have optimized request handling, while Node.js applications may have additional overhead for data serialization, deserialization, and error handling.


Tips for Optimizing Node.js Performance:

Minimize Network Latency: Choose a Vertex AI region closer to your Node.js application.

Optimize Model Loading: Implement caching or batching techniques.

Efficient Request Handling: Use asynchronous operations and minimize data transfer.

Profiling and Optimization: Use profiling tools to identify bottlenecks and optimize your code.



None of this is the root cause. vertex ai takes time to authenticate. so the first call takes time after that subsequent calls will have less latency.
